# Registration of Apple Pass Type Certificate

Tags: wallet

I implement feature of issuing Apple Wallet Pass for one of my clients.
I plan to offer this feature to another clients. For each client Apple Pass Type Certificate is required.

Who have to register Apple Pass Type Certificate. Me or my client? From one side I don`t want to add some difficulties for my clients and it is easy to register certificate by my self. From another side I am not sure which risk I will have in this case.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your client has to provide you with the certificate.

There is an extensive attachment (Attachment 5) in the developer terms and conditions (you can find these under documents when logged into the Apple Developer Portal) that details how certificates can per used.

> **Pass Type ID Usage and Restrictions**
>
> You may use the Pass Type ID only for purposes of digitally signing
>   Your Pass for use with Wallet and/or for purposes of using the APN
>   service with Your Pass.  You may distribute Your Pass Type ID as
>   incorporated into Your Pass in accordance with Section 2 below only so
>   long as such distribution is under Your own trademark or brand. To the
>   extent that You reference a third party’s trademark or brand within
>   Your Pass (e.g., a store coupon for a particular good), You represent
>   and warrant that You have any necessary rights.  You agree not to
>   share, provide or transfer Your Pass Type ID to any third party
>   (except for a Service Provider and only to the limited extent
>   permitted herein), nor use Your Pass Type ID to sign a third party's
>   pass

Comment: As I understand, "except for a Service Provider and only to the limited extent permitted herein" is a my case. I`m right?

Comment: Unless you own the trademark or brand, you as the Service Provider cannot supply the certificate.  The _(except for a Service Provider and only to the limited extent permitted herein)_ part gives your client permission to share _their_ certificate with you.

Comment: And the _"nor use Your Pass Type ID to sign a third party's pass"_ prevents you from signing a client's pass with your certificate.

Comment: Let`s imagine that I have public User Agreement, and by accepting it, my client gives me part of rights on his trademark and this part of rights allow me to register cert by my self and sign passes for users.

Comment: It’s not for me to determine, you would need to talk directly with Apple, but every conversation we have had with them has led to the same answer.  If you look at Apple’s recent action of revoking Facebook and Google’s Enterprise developer certificates for breaching the developer agreement, you’ll see that no-one is to big (or too small) to bend their rules.  It’s your business and your choice at the end of the day, you get to decide if you are willing to take the risk.